# In Oracle, how to catch exception when table used for the loop doesn't exists

Tags: oracle

I have this code:

```
BEGIN
    FOR
        U1 IN (SELECT * FROM SOME_USER.SOME_TABLE)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            -- do something;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

My problem is that sometimes `SOME_USER.SOMETABLE` do not exists but I want the rest of the script to be run. I know that checking if the table exists before running the code (in a `IF ... THEN` block) will not work because `SELECT * FROM SOME_USER.SOME_TABLE` is evaluated at compile time.

So another avenue is to run the `SELECT` with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. This way it will be evaluated at run time and I would be able to catch the exception. Unfortunately I can't find a way to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with my `U1 IN` loop. How I should achieve this?

I'm on Oracle 11g and the SQL script is run from a batch script on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the 'OPEN FOR' syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/openfor_statement.htm#LNPLS01333):

```
DECLARE
    CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
    <variables or record type> -- declare as appropriate
BEGIN
    OPEN CUR FOR 'SELECT * FROM SOME_USER.SOME_TABLE';
    LOOP
        FETCH CUR INTO <variables or record type>;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
        -- do something with variables or record
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR;
END;
/
```

You need to fetch each row into variables or a record type, you can't use `%ROWTYPE` as the table still won't exist; and you can change to do bulk fetches if that's appropriate for your data volumes.

If you run that you'll still get ORA-00942, but if this is in a stored program you won't get it until run time, and you can now add an `IF` block to check for the table's existence before the `OPEN`.

Having a data model where objects may or may not exist at run-time seems rather fishy though...

Comment: I'd rather do this than mine as it doesn't need any external objects and you don't have to worry about LIMIT'ing results of bulk collect if the result of the select is millions of rows. (Although row-by-row could be slower than bulk collect in most situations) :)

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you could also do FETCH ... BULK COLLECT... if you think performance is a concern.

Comment: I think this is the closest way to get the expected result, but you need to create the variable to fetch results first, you can use `record` as you can't use some_table%rowtype if table don't exists

Comment: Yes, should have shown something in the declaration section.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I'll try it later today. I agree with you that having user and/or table that may or may not exist is fishy but it's only for a short term solution and a proper mid-term solution is in the works.

Comment: OK, I tested it and this works fine. I added Exception catching like @Mina have suggest. I think the complete correct answer is yours combined with Mina's. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Etienne - yes, I liked Mina's extension of this approach too - simpler than querying to see if the table exists.

Answer (score 4):

Proposed solution with cursor is fine, I would add an exception handling for  this particular exception : Table or view does not exist ORA-00942.

```
DECLARE
    e_missing_t EXCEPTION;
    pragma exception_init (e_missing_t,-942);
    something number; --some variable you need to fetch to
    CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN CUR FOR 'SELECT * FROM SOME_USER.SOME_TABLE';
    LOOP
        FETCH CUR INTO something;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
        -- do something with variables or record
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_missing_t THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('some_table is missing');
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful. As I said in my last comment to @Alex Poole, I think the complete correct answer is yours combined with Alex's answer. Unfortunately I had to choose only one...

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a workaround -
Create a nested table type and store the results of the SELECT in it. Use that type to loop through values.

So,

```
SELECT data_obj(COL1, COL2) bulk collect into data_tbl_typ from data_table;
```

This part can go in the dynamic sql. (Remember to use bind variables)

And then just loop through this nested table type in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DBMS_SQL package to run the query.

Follow the examples in this Oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#sthref6147

Comment: effectively compile it at run time.

Answer (score -1):

pl/sql has the exception clause for that.   OTHERS catches pretty much everything.   You can deal with the exception in the function, or print a message and pass it back to the main.   Break your function up into smaller functions and have each one catch it's own exception.

```
BEGIN
    FOR
        U1 IN (SELECT * FROM SOME_USER.SOME_TABLE)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            -- do something;
        END;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Oh well.  The table isn't there.');
        --RAISE;


END;
```

Comment: This is a compilation error though, not a run-time error?

Comment: If I'm not wrong (I'm pretty new to Oracle), Exception are raise at runtime but the error triggered by the `SELECT` is done at compile time. So, in your code, the Exception will not be trigger because the error raised at compile time will prevent the code to run. No?